# Learning Elixir and confused about atoms

Tags: elixir

I am confused about atoms and how to use them.

To be honest I am reading the documentation and just not understanding atoms :(

Can someone provide some examples or something that would explain this?

Thanks

Comment: What language are you coming from? It might be easier to explain the concept to you in terms relating to your previous experiences.

Comment: I know javascript

Answer (score 6):

You may just be over thinking it. An atom is just a value. Just like `true` and `false` are just values, you now have any word you can use as a value. In fact `true`, `false` and `nil` are just atoms under the hood.

Instead of passing strings around your application as internal messages, you can pass atoms. And instead of using strings as keys for maps or keyword lists you can use atoms.

Atoms come with 1 very large caveat, they are never garbage collected so you should never generate atoms programmatically, from user input or otherwise, otherwise you risk overflowing the VM if too many are created.

The maximum number of atoms you can create defaults to 1,048,576. http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html

Here's some examples: https://github.com/itsgreggreg/elixir_quick_reference#atom

Comment: Can you explain the caveat then?  Since they are never garbage collected, how do you handle a situation where you get a ton of atoms?  Like if I am doing message streams and I use atom for the keys?  Thanks

Comment: Elixir/Erlang is never going to generate atoms automatically, you would have to do it yourself. If you are taking input and converting it to atoms you are at risk of crashing your VM, that is why you never convert input to atoms.

Answer (score 5):

Since this question isn't that specific, I'll just give an example usage.

One popular use of atoms in Elixir is to use them as messages for pattern matching.

E.g., say you have function which does some sort of processing of a http request. The outcome of this processing is either going to be a successful process, or a failed process.

You could therefore use atoms to indicate whether or not this processing is successful. E.g.

```
def process(file) do
  lines = file |> split_lines

  case lines do
    nil ->
      {:error, "failed to process file"}
    lines ->
      {:ok, lines}
  end
end
```

Here we are saying that the method, `process/1` will return a two tuple response. If the result of our processing is successful, it will return `{:ok, lines}`, however if it fails (e.g. returns nil) then it will return an error. This therefore allows us to pattern match on this result.

```
{:ok, lines} = process('text.txt')
```

Therefore, we can be sure that we will always have the lines returned to us and never a nil value (because it will throw an error). This becomes extremely useful when piping multiple methods together.

For more general information on atoms, checkout these links:

[Elixir School](https://elixirschool.com/lessons/basics/basics/#atoms)

[Stack overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261500/why-is-useful-to-have-a-atom-type-like-in-elixir-erlang)

Answer (score 5):

from http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html#atoms

> Atoms are constants where their name is their own value. Some other
>   languages call these symbols

So if you are coming from a mainstream language, they are most like constants.  But more similar (ish) to a global enum in use (ie, they act like an independent data type).  You introduce them generally as targets to be matched against, so they name things that your code needs some concept of

true / false is a classic case

`:ok`, `:error` is something else you will see

you might want `:red, :green, :blue`,  or `:yes, :no, :maybe`,  or `:up, :down, :left, :right`  if those concepts are important code wise  ( like a 2d game )

Answer (score 4):

Atoms are:

- immutable like everything in Elixir
- values like `:patryk` or `:true` (because `true` is actually `:true`)
- similar to symbols in Ruby
- great for keys in maps, because enable nice syntax for accessing map elements
- enables you to use Keyword Lists- list that are actually list of tuples, but with easier access
- foundation of message communication eg. with GenServer

## Atom in maps

Map without atom can be created like that:

```
map = %{"author" => "patNowak"}
```

and accessed

```
map["author"]
> "patNowak"
```

Map with atom as key can be created easier:

```
map = %{author: "patNowak"} # but %{:author => "patNowak"} still works
```

and accessed:

```
map.author # as well as map[:author]
> "patNowak"
```

## Atom in Keyword List

Keyword list is actually list of tuple(s):

```
list = [author: "patNowak"]
list === [{:author, "patNowak"}]
> true
```

And can be accessed:

```
list[:author] # no dot notation in this case
```

## Atom in messaging

GenServer use by default `:reply` or `:noreply` in some cases (GS's functions `call` and `cast` will wait for these particular atoms from your `handle_` functions). Most of the messages you will receive (not warnings and errors) will be atoms eg. IO.puts "hi" will print `hi` and return `:ok`.